# I'm trying to create a table but i keep getting Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "postagens.titulo"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, body-parser

I just want to create a table in my database. But every time I try to start my server I get the giant error saying:

> Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "postagens.titulo"

```js
const Db = require('./Db')

const Post = Db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
    titulo: {
        type: Db.sequelize.STRING
    },
    conteudo: {
        type: Db.sequelize.TEXT
    }
});

Post.sync({force: true});
```

Comment: If you have already created the table then do share the schema of `postagens` too.

Comment: I haven't. Thas what i'm trying to do. ;-;

Comment: In that case can you also share the Db module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STRING` and `TEXT` should be coming from the Sequelize module directly, not from your database instance.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Db = require('./Db')

const Post = Db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
    titulo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    conteudo: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
});

Post.sync({force: true});
```